# Insert edgerings along selected edge loops

Tags: modeling, topology

This is a useful 2.6 add-on in order to insert an edge. Unfortunately, it does not work in Blender 2.72.

Is there any way to do it in a simple way ? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

[image]

P.S.: When using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, "Dissolve Verts" needn't being toggled every time. It will remember your last choice.